# How can I find the first few terms of the Laurent series for this function?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

For each of the following functions find the first few terms of each of the Laurent series about the origin, that is, one series for each annular ring between singular points.  Find the residue of each function at the origin.

The function is...

$$\frac{1}{z(z-1)(z-2)^2 }$$

I did partial fraction expansion and got $\frac{1}{z-1}- \frac{1}{4z} - \frac{3}{4(z-2)} + \frac{1}{2(z-2)^2}$ but am not sure where to go from here... Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the linear terms,
$\frac1{z-a}
=\frac{-1}{a}\frac1{1-z/a}
=\frac{-1}{a}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{z^n}{a^n}
$.

For higher powers
$\frac1{(z-a)^m}
=\frac{(-1)^m}{a^m}\frac1{(1-z/a)^m}
=\frac{(-1)^m}{a^m}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\binom{-m}{n}\frac{z^n}{a^n}
$

Note that
$(-1)^n\binom{-m}{n}
=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (-m-k)
=\frac{1}{n!}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (m+k)
=\frac{1}{n!}\frac{(m+n-1)!}{(m-1)!}
=\binom{m+n-1}{n}
$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, how would I go about finding the first terms of a Laurent series for each of the annular rings, 0<z<1, 1<z<2, and z>2 once I have written it as a power series.